Can a person die if it’s not Hashem’s will?
I learned about a machloket between Rishonim, regarding free will and its power on other people. The basic argument of the machloket was that either free will is so powerful that one could commit a murder even if Hashem didn’t decree for the victim to die, or that Hashem only allows things to happen to people if they deserve it and people only have free will to be the one to do the action.
Anyone have any sources for either opinion? I believe one of the sides was Rambam.

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.37.21.1?lang=he

Where do you get that God protects people from undeserved harm?

https://musingsonthetorah.blogspot.com/2023/02/can-people-intentionally-harm-other_16.html

אם ה' לי לא אירא, מה יעשה לי אדם?
